# C - Qsort: Sort name in ascending order and grade in descending order

Tags: c, sorting, typedef, strcmp, qsort

I am trying to qsort my record so that it will sort the records by name in ascending order.  If there are name with the same name, it will sort their grades in descending order

For example: The original textfile

```
simpson bart 25
simpson bart 35
simpson lisa 90
simpson bart 34
```

Desired output:

```
simpson bart 35
simpson bart 34
simpson bart 25
simpson lisa 90
```

This is what I have:

```
int sort_nameasc_gradedes(const void *p, const void *q)
{
    const record *pp = p;
    const record *qq = q;

    int n1 = strcmp(pp->name.first, qq->name.first);
    int n2 = strcmp(pp->name.last, qq->name.last);

    if (n2 == 0 && n1 != 0) {
        return n1;
    } else if (n2 != 0  && n1 == 0) {
        return n2;
    } else {
        return (pp->score - qq->score);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are sorting on three fields, but your description only talks about 2.

Comment: While it is unlikely to be a problem here, in general you should avoid using `return (pp->score - qq->score);` as it has undefined behaviour if the values are large enough to cause overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to check the fields one at a time, and return as soon as one pair of fields is not equal.  So first compare `name.last` and keep the `strcmp` result; if it's not zero, return it, otherwise proceed to the next field.  Then, compare `name.first` the same way... returning if the `strcmp` result was not zero.  Finally, compare `score`.

If `score` is signed and won't be near the extremes of the data type used, you can use a subtraction as your test like you did, but if unsigned or if the subtraction could wrap you'd need a different sort of test.

Something like the following may work:

```
int sort_nameasc_gradedes(const void *p, const void *q)
{
    const record *pp = p;
    const record *qq = q;
    int r;

    if ((r = strcmp(pp->name.last, qq->name.last)) != 0)
        return r;
    if ((r = strcmp(pp->name.first, qq->name.first)) != 0)
        return r;
    /* return pp->score - qq->score; */
    return (pp->score < qq->score) ? 1 : ((pp->score > qq->score) ? -1 : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you are looking for.

```
int sort_nameasc_gradedes(const void *p, const void *q)
{
    const record *pp = p;
    const record *qq = q;

    int n1 = strcmp(pp->name.first, qq->name.first);
    int n2 = strcmp(pp->name.last, qq->name.last);

    if (n1 != 0) {
        return n1;
    } else if (n2 != 0) {
        return n2;
    } else {
        return (qq->score - pp->score);
    }
}
```

First think what you have done in the first and second condition. You wrote:

```
if (n2 == 0 && n1 != 0) {
        return n1;
}
```

What if inputs are:

```
simpson bart 25
taufique hussain 30
```

Decision for this input should based on first name, but in your code it would be decided at the last `else` condition and it would make the output

```
taufique hussain 30
simpson bart 25
```

instead of

```
simpson bart 25
taufique hussain 30
```

Now come to the last condition. If `pp` is `simpson bart 25` and `qq` is `simpson bart 30`, what is the value of `pp->score - qq->score` ? `-5` right? Then in the sorted array following would be the answer:

```
simpson bart 25
simpson bart 30
```

Instead of your desired:

```
simpson bart 30
simpson bart 25
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something more like this:

```
int sort_nameasc_gradedes(const void *p, const void *q)
{
    const record *pp = p;
    const record *qq = q;

    int n2 = strcmp(pp->name.last, qq->name.last);

    if (n2 != 0)
    {
        return n2;
    }
    else
    {
        int n1 = strcmp(pp->name.first, qq->name.first);

        if (n1 != 0)
        {
            return n1;
        }
        else
        {
            return qq->score - pp->score;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the "pp->score - qq->score" part? Did you thought it right? I think it should be "qq->score - pp->score" according to his requirement.

Comment: Good point, I've updated the example above. (I was going with what was in OP's code, rather than requirements)